# Check if checkbox is checked then do function (not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
  <h4>Meal Time</h4>
  <div class="checkbox1">
    <input type="checkbox" value=".breakfast"/>
    <label>Breakfast</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" value=".lunch"/>
    <label>Lunch</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox3">
    <input type="checkbox" value=".dinner"/>
    <label>Dinner</label>
  </div>
    <div class="checkbox4">
    <input type="checkbox" value=".snacks"/>
    <label>Snacks</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**JS**

```
var rangesliderfilter = function () {
    var low = parseInt(jQuery('#min-value-span').text());
    var high = parseInt(jQuery('#max-value-span').text());
    var BreakfastDR = [];
    var LunchDR = [];
    var DinnerDR = [];
    var SnacksDR = [];
    var TheString = []; /*This is the var I want the string to be in*/
    while (low <= high) {
        BreakfastDR.push('.' + low +'.breakfast');
        LunchDR.push('.' + low +'.lunch');
        DinnerDR.push('.' + low +'.dinner');
        SnacksDR.push('.' + low +'.snacks');
        low++;
}

    if (jQuery(".checkbox1 input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){
        TheString.push(BreakfastDR)
    }
    if (jQuery(".checkbox2 input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){
        TheString.push(LunchDR)
    }
    if (jQuery(".checkbox3 input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){
        TheString.push(DinnerDR)
    }
    if (jQuery(".checkbox4 input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){
        TheString.push(SnacksDR)
    }

jQuery('.rangecheck').attr('value', TheString);
}
```

**The Goal**

To create a string that follows this pattern:

Just breakfast checked: `.0.breakfast,.1.breakfast,.2.breakfast,etc`
Breakfast and lunch checked: `.0.breakfast,.1.breakfast,.2.breakfast,.0.lunch,.1.lunch,.2.lunch`

If any others were selected it would continue the patter just with .dinner or .snacks trailing every number.

Here is a JS fiddle with the JS code starting at line 140

[Click here for JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtree5757/suqqU/2/)

Strings are output to console

**How can I achieve my goal?**

Answer (score 1):

Your `Uncaught SyntaxError` is happening because you're missing the period before `is`. Also, as Arun mentioned below, you're missing parens around your conditional:

```
if(jQuery(".checkbox1 input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){
    TheString.push(BreakfastDR)
}
if(jQuery(".checkbox2 input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){
    TheString.push(LunchDR)
}
if(jQuery(".checkbox3 input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){
    TheString.push(DinnerDR)
}
if(jQuery(".checkbox4 input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){
    TheString.push(SnacksDR)
}
```

Comment: good catch, but it still didn;t fix the error. It is somewhere in that block of code (the if statements) because there is no error when I take it out

Comment: Thank you I updated my question with the correct syntax. Do you know why I'm not getting the results I want. It looks fine to me

Comment: Are you getting the error when you remove `[Corresponding vars that are checked separated]` from `var TheString = [Corresponding vars that are checked separated]`? That's likely where your error is coming in--I originally thought that was just an un-commented comment for the question, but is it in the original?

Comment: No, it is just a comment. Sorry about that, I'll update question. I have a Js fiddle up too if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy, but I think you might be able to go about this in a different way. Update your HTML so all checkboxes you want to validate have the same class:

```
<fieldset>
  <h4>Meal Time</h4>
  <div class="checkbox1">
    <input type="checkbox" value=".breakfast" class="checkMe"/>
    <label>Breakfast</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" value=".lunch" class="checkMe"/>
    <label>Lunch</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox3">
    <input type="checkbox" value=".dinner" class="checkMe"/>
    <label>Dinner</label>
  </div>
    <div class="checkbox4">
    <input type="checkbox" value=".snacks" class="checkMe"/>
    <label>Snacks</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Then perform your check in your function using `.each()`

```
var rangesliderfilter = function () {
    var low = parseInt($('#min-value-span').text(),10),
        high = parseInt($('#max-value-span').text(),10),
        LunchDR = [],
        DinnerDR = [],
        SnacksDR = [],
        TheString = []; //Corresponding vars that are checked separated

    while (low <= high) {
        BreakfastDR.push('.' + low +'.breakfast');
        LunchDR.push('.' + low +'.lunch');
        DinnerDR.push('.' + low +'.dinner');
        SnacksDR.push('.' + low +'.snacks');
        low++;
    }

    $('.checkMe').each(function(i){
        var self = this;

        if(self.checked){
            switch(i+1){
                case 1:
                    TheString.push(BreakfastDR);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    TheString.push(LunchDR);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    TheString.push(DinnerDR);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    TheString.push(SnacksDR);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    $('.rangecheck').val(TheString);
}
```

This will perform the same validation you are doing with the `if ... is.(':checked')` using WAY less overhead. Additionally ... don't use `.attr('value')` unless you're using like jQuery 1.4. `.val()` is pretty standard at this point. And when using `parseInt`, always include the base parameter, which is usually base 10 if you are doing a standard parse.

Comment: This looked promising, but didn't do it. I have a Js fiddle up and I have the string being output to console. The checkboxes for the menu items also output a string so just ignore that. You will see what I mean